# Google Earth Engine: Get a Geometry object based on user's drawing

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

In order to publish my code as a Google Earth Engine App, I need to interactively set the Area of Interest (AOI) of the analysis  based on the users's drawing (Rectangle in this case). I'm trying to use the `.onDraw()` method as described in the `ui.Map.DrawingTools` and `ui.Map.GeometryLayer` documentation examples but I cannot seem to make it work. I'm trying the following:

```
// Don't make imports that correspond to the drawn rectangles.
Map.drawingTools().setLinked(false);
// Limit the draw modes to rectangles.
Map.drawingTools().setDrawModes(['rectangle']);
// Add an empty layer to hold the drawn rectangle.
Map.drawingTools().addLayer([]);
// Set the geometry type to be rectangle.
Map.drawingTools().setShape('rectangle');
// Enter drawing mode.
var getAOI = Map.drawingTools().draw();

var getAOI = function(){
  Map.drawingTools().layers().get(0).toGeometry();
};

var AOI = Map.drawingTools().onDraw(getAOI);
```

Here is a link to the full script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/11a77302259a6d99c3a561a2a723fca0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onDraw()` takes a callback function, which according to docs:

> The callback to fire when a shape is drawn. The callback is passed
>   three parameters: the added ee.Geometry, the GeometryLayer to which
>   the geometry was added, and the ui.Map.DrawingTools widget that the
>   event listener is bound to.

This means, you get a reference to the geometry like this:

```
Map.drawingTools().onDraw(function (geometry) {
  // Do something with the geometry
  Map.addLayer(geometry, null, 'a drawn geometry')
})
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Wiell for clarifying that.